# Java URL getContent Android

Tags: java, android, url

I have no idea how to do what I am doing, and I am just trying to hack something together really quickly.

But here's what I've got:

```
public void newScanThing(String scanFormat, String scanContent){
    URL u;
    try {
        u = new URL("http://www.searchupc.com/handlers/upcsearch.ashx?request_type=3&access_token=A98AC4EC-830D-4F6B-89D6-D6954361A8CA&upc=" + scanContent.toString());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(u.openStream()));
        String stringBuff;
        String scanData = "";
        while ((stringBuff = br.readLine()) != null){
            scanData += stringBuff;

        }
        br.close();

        formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat + " DATA: I don't crash.");
    } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
        // crash
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        // crash
    }I know which line causes it to crash, and it is the scanData = new ... line. But I have no idea why. If you were to visit the link I visit, you would see the only thing in that URL is a single string. It's not even any HTML or anything, it's just a string.
```

Here is my function call:

```
 newScanThing("UPC_A","816983011311");
```

Anyways, what the heck am I doing wrong? I've never used this before. And I need to get this string for a proof of concept due in about 12 hours, and I have a lot of work to do after I get the string. So tips? Gestures at the right answer?

Maybe just a quick and dirty explanation of what I am doing wrong, how to do it right and why it works that way?

LogCat:

```
01-25 05:53:42.367: D/libEGL(13564): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
```

01-25 05:53:42.382: D/libEGL(13564): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
01-25 05:53:42.390: D/libEGL(13564): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
01-25 05:53:42.492: D/OpenGLRenderer(13564): Enabling debug mode 0
01-25 05:53:42.500: E/SensorManager(13564): thread start
01-25 05:53:42.507: D/SensorManager(13564): registerListener :: handle = 1  name= BMA254 Acceleration Sensor delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41816ab8
01-25 05:53:42.593: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(13564): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
01-25 05:53:54.406: D/AndroidRuntime(13564): Shutting down VM
01-25 05:53:54.406: W/dalvikvm(13564): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4106a2a0)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:70)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:50)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:462)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at com.example.food2forkbarcode.MainActivity.newScanThing(MainActivity.java:60)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at com.example.food2forkbarcode.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:28)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4222)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17273)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
01-25 05:53:54.421: E/AndroidRuntime(13564):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-25 05:54:02.820: I/Process(13564): Sending signal. PID: 13564 SIG: 9
01-25 05:54:10.656: D/libEGL(13768): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
01-25 05:54:10.664: D/libEGL(13768): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
01-25 05:54:10.671: D/libEGL(13768): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
01-25 05:54:10.781: D/OpenGLRenderer(13768): Enabling debug mode 0
01-25 05:54:10.789: E/SensorManager(13768): thread start
01-25 05:54:10.789: D/SensorManager(13768): registerListener :: handle = 1  name= BMA254 Acceleration Sensor delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@41813160
01-25 05:54:12.187: D/AndroidRuntime(13768): Shutting down VM
01-25 05:54:12.187: W/dalvikvm(13768): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4106a2a0)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:70)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:50)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:462)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at com.example.food2forkbarcode.MainActivity.newScanThing(MainActivity.java:60)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at com.example.food2forkbarcode.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:28)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4222)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17273)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
01-25 05:54:12.203: E/AndroidRuntime(13768):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-25 05:55:03.835: D/dalvikvm(13768): GC_CONCURRENT freed 245K, 9% free 7464K/8199K, paused 6ms+3ms, total 44ms
01-25 05:57:28.851: D/dalvikvm(13768): GC_CONCURRENT freed 332K, 11% free 7572K/8455K, paused 16ms+2ms, total 63ms

Comment: Please show us your LogCat.

Comment: I'm sorry, what is LogCat? I've never made an adroid app before.

Comment: Figured it out, editing it in.,

Comment: Please post the FULL LogCat corresponding to the crash. The line you posted is not relevant.

Comment: Oh, let me try again. I found something much larger. But it's huge...

Comment: Should be at least 15 lines.

Comment: Is that it? If not, I'm not sure I have any idea what it is.

Comment: It's a bit too much, and not formatted, but it's the right thing, yes ;)

Comment: Thanks for bearing witrh me. I've not written in java in 3 years, never for android, and I've never dealt with URL things in any language. Plus. like I said, 5am. Dazed, confused, and the caffine has worn off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually multiple issues in your code:

1. You are converting an InputStream to a String in this line:

   ```
   scanData = new String(u.getContent().toString());
   ```

   Which certainly is not what you want.

   An `InputStream` provides you the *way* to get data, but it does not represent the data itself. You have to read the bytes from the InputStream before initializing any String.
2. You are doing a networking operation on the main thread. The problem is that networking operations take time, and if you perform them on the UI thread, you will block the UI, the app will get unresponsive. For this reason, performing Networking activity on the UI thread is prohibited by the System and causes the `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` that is crashing your app. You'll have to move your networking code to another thread. I'd recommend an `AsyncTask` for that.

Have a look at a networking tutorial like this one: http://android-er.blogspot.co.at/2012/04/androidosnetworkonmainthreadexception.html

Comment: Ok, yeah, that sounds about right. Uh, so how do I do that? something like scanData = new String((Bytes[])u.getContent().toString()); ?

Comment: I'll extend my answer.

Comment: Added details to my answer.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I don't have any idea what you're saying in part 2. How do I fix this issue? Can I somehow make a new thread or something? How do you make threads, if so? Did I solve the issue in part 1?

Comment: Using code like in the tutorial I linked will solve all your problems (except won't get you sleep)

Comment: What is this, a tutorial for ants?! But seriously, thanks. If I can figure it out from here, I'll check mark you. Unless I pass out.

Comment: My eclipse says readline is depreciated... and the tutorial says to use it. Is this ok?

Comment: I get this error: "Description Resource Path Location Type
The method readline() is undefined for the type BufferedReader MainActivity.java /Food2ForkBarCode/src/com/example/food2forkbarcode line 63 Java Problem
"

Comment: I.. god.. fahhh... Sorry. Ok, but now it's crashing again. I'll edit in new code and log thingy

Comment: I'd suggest opening a new question for that.

Comment: Ok, tiny question left, I have to edit a text field in class A from class B. I'm just not understanding this. I've got the async business working after re-reading your example a dozen times. Turns out I missed a few small things in my first dozen reads.

Comment: Please start a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running on the Main Thread - the application's UI thread. This is why you are getting a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Move your network code to an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

A child of **AsyncTask**

```
public class AsyncLoadData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private Context mContext;
    private ILoadDataListener mListener;

    public AsyncLoadData(Context context, ILoadDataListener listener) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String url = params[0];
        String result = doGetStringFromUrl(url); // You can write your own method;
                return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        mListener.complete(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mListener.loading();
    }

    public interface ILoadDataListener {
        void loading();

        void complete(String result);
    }
}
```

In your **activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AsyncLoadData.ILoadDataListener {
      /// Something...
     public void getData() {
         new AsyncLoadData(this, this).execute(url);
         // or new AsyncLoadData(getBaseContext(), this).execute(url);
     }

     @Override
     public void loading() {
        // Do something here when you start download and downloading text
     }

     @Override
     public void complete(String result) {
         TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_text_view);
         mTextView.setText(result);
     }
}
```